# Create a table with blank squares for missing mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've written a PHP script that can populate a table in a particular way so that multiple events (or no events) can be put in one square  in an HTML - similar to the layout a calendar would have. But, there's a problem, the while statement I created to fill in squares in the table when there is no data doesn't detect when there is data, and fills the entire table with empty squares. [This is what the output looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIHbE.png) (The page is styled using Bootstrap 3). From the mysql data I have provided, these events should be in the square at {Period 1, Monday}.

Here is my data in a mysql database; [mysql data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi8nX.png)

Here is a snippet of the part of the page related to this table;

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM configtimetabletwo WHERE term = ".$term." AND week = ".$week." ORDER BY period, day LIMIT 100;";
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);   
$pp=1; //The current y value of the table
$pd=0; //The current x value of the table 
echo '<tr><td>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($results)) {
while((pd!=$row[3] or $pp!=$row[4]) and $pp<6){ //This while statement fills in empty squares and numbers each row.
if($pd==0)  {
            echo $pp."</td><td>";
            $pd++;
            }
elseif($pd<5){
            echo "</td><td>";
            $pd++;
             }
else    {
            echo "</td></tr><tr><td>";
            $pd=0;
            $pp++;
        }
    }
    echo '<a href="?edit='.$row[0].'" class="label label-default">';
    echo $row[5].' '.$row[6].' - '.$row[7]."</a><br>";
}
echo "</td></tr></table>"
?>
```

I haven't been able to figure out why this happens so far, thanks in advance to anyone who has any idea what's going on.

Comment: `while((pd!=$row[3] or $pp!=$row[4]) and $pp<6){` missing `$` sign in the beginning

Comment: In PHP instead of `or` and `and` is better to use `||` and `&&`

Comment: Thanks, that has completely fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments below my question, pavlovich pointed out the error. In this case, it was **simply an issue of forgetting to use a $ to reference a variable**. It would seem that this doesn't throw an error in a while statement like it would elsewhere.